# How can I use '-v' option in time command?

Tags: bash, time

I read the man pages and the '-v' option(short for --verbose) is there and I'm sure this should work:

```
 time -v ls
```

However, the output is:

```
-v: Command not found.
0.000u 0.000s 0:00.00 0.0%      0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w
```

I typed the command according to the man pages in the order of 'time argument(s) command'. 
I can't see where I made a mistake here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `bash`:

```
$ type -a time
time is a shell keyword
time is /usr/bin/time
```

You called `time`, cause `bash` invoked [time](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pipelines) built in keyword instead of external [/usr/bin/time](http://linux.die.net/man/1/time) command. `time` built in keyword does not have option `-v`. `bash` interpreted that you calling built in `time` on command `-v`, causing this error.

Try:

```
/usr/bin/time -v ls
```

or:

```
command time -v ls
```

Comment: @JechtTyre As far as I'm concerned, I get a valid, satisfying result in both cases. What do you mean by *"the second doesn't [work]"*? Do you get an error? Unexpected behaviour?

Comment: My bad. Both your commands are correct.